# Cannot find my Task field in Designer Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow

I added a Column called "Release Phase" to my Task list via List Settings.

I then went to my workflow in Designer and refreshed. I expected to see the Column name in "Task Field" workflow action but I don't see it.  Any ideas how I can access/set that column field from my workflows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was it added to the content type associated to the list when you created the column? Did you leave the 2 check boxes ticked that Said Add to default view and add to all content types?